# Testing views that use CanCan and Devise with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, cancan

I was trying to test a simple index view, which has following code inside:

```
- if can? :destroy, MyModel
  %th Options
```

`MyModelsController` has following options (Inherited Resources + CanCan + Devise):

```
class MyModelsController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources
  nested_belongs_to :mymodel
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :mymodel, :through => :project
```

When running specs, it crashes at the line `- if can? :destroy, MyModel`

```
Failure/Error: render
   ActionView::Template::Error:
      undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

There's no traceback, nothing to base on...

I thought that maybe I'm not authorized and signed when testing views, but `Devise::TestHelpers` should only be included in controller tests (and that's how I have it).

I was trying to override method can? in both `Ability` and the controller, but that gave no effect.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is described in the [CanCan docs for controller testing](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities), and can also be modified to apply to view specs. Here's one way to do it:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "mymodel/index.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:my_model,mock_model(MyModel))
    @ability = Object.new
    @ability.extend(CanCan::Ability)
    controller.stub(:current_ability) { @ability }
  end

  context "authorized user" do
    it "can see the table header" do
      @ability.can :destroy, MyModel
      render
      rendered.should have_selector('th:contains("Options")')
    end
  end

  context "unauthorized user" do
    it "cannot see the table header" do
      render
      rendered.should_not have_selector('th:contains("Options")')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed it, but it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I also had to stub `view.current_ability` as well as on `controller` but this was perfect

Answer (score 6):

The 'before :each' code posted by zetetic doesn't work for me. My views bork on the 'can?' method because 'current_ability' in the view returns nil. I fixed it by using this 'before :each' code instead:

```
@ability = Ability.new(user)
assign(:current_ability, @ability)
controller.stub(:current_user, user)
view.stub(:current_user, user)
```

The above code simulates a login.

Answer (score 6):

In your spec_helper:

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view
```

In your view spec:

```
controller.stub!(current_user: [some user])
view.stub!(current_user: [some user])
```

Comment: worked! I had tried to include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller before BUT still had a probled. including helpers to view fixed )

Comment: Works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For new RSpec 3.0 syntax

```
  before(:each) do
    assign(:my_model,mock_model(MyModel))
    @ability = Object.new.extend(CanCan::Ability)
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_ability).and_return(@ability)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the solution from the CanCan wiki is that it requires a `@ability. can ...` in each example, which doesn't feel very DRY.

Moreover, it doesn't actually stub out the abilities themselves, but the method that returns the controller's ability. The ability is not a stub and consequently the abilities are checked.

If you're using Rspec and want to test just the controller (and not it's abilities), here's how to stub it out:

```
before(:each) do
  ability = mock(:ability).as_null_object
  controller.stub(:current_ability).and_return(ability)
end
```

This works because `as_null_object` returns truthy values for all methods, so the ability checking methods pass.

Answer (score 0):

Based on John Kloian's example I defined this useful helper:

```
# spec/support/sign_in.rb
module ViewSpecSignInHelper
  def login_as(user)
    allow(view).to       receive(:signed_in?).and_return   true
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return user
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ViewSpecSignInHelper, type: :view
end
```

My full `spec/support/sign_in.rb` looks like this:

```
module ControllerSpecSignInHelper
  def login_as(user)
    sign_in(user)
  end
end

module FeatureSpecSignInHelper
  # See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Capybara
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  # A login_as(user) method is provided already!
end

module ViewSpecSignInHelper
  def login_as(user)
    allow(view).to       receive(:signed_in?).and_return   true
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return user
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view

  config.include ControllerSpecSignInHelper, type: :controller
  config.include FeatureSpecSignInHelper, type: :feature
  config.include ViewSpecSignInHelper, type: :view
end
```

I can now login a user the same way in feature, controller, and view specs:

```
user = create :user # Using FactoryBot
login_as user
```